# Display video only when url is there

Tags: php

I am trying to make it so that my `$content` string displays the following `$content .= ''.$row['content'].'';` all times unless there is a video within the `video` portion of my database.

Then I would make it display

```
$content .= ''.$row['content'].'<br><br><iframe type="text/html" width="100%" height="390" src="'.$row['video'].'" frameborder="0"/>';
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: By building a logic using `isset();` or `empty();` or other similar functions that check data.

Comment: @Epodax can you show me an example please?

Comment: No, there's plenty of guides out there, the php.net page contains multiple examples for the uses of `isset();`and `empty();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $row['video'] is null when its empty you can use this code,

```
if($row['video']){ //if its not NULL
  $content .= ''.$row['content'].'<br><br><iframe type="text/html" width="100%" height="390" src="'.$row['video'].'" frameborder="0"/>';
}else{
  $content .= ''.$row['content'].'';
}
```

Not sure why people like to be rude, but all the best to you buddy :)

Answer (score -1):

```
if(isset($row['video']) && $row['video']!=""){ //if its not NULL
  $content .= ''.$row['content'].'<br><br><iframe type="text/html" width="100%" height="390" src="'.$row['video'].'" frameborder="0"/>';
}else{
  $content .= ''.$row['content'].'';
}
```

Comment: isset($row['video']) is not needed in this case, as I doubt the query will be changing at all. EG:"select content,video from exampletable", so $row['video'] will always be set.